# xml reading nodes and children nodes

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

i have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dictionary>
<Object name="Ship">
    <Struct_Name>tb_Ship</Struct_Name>
        <Owner> ..... </Owner>
           <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
        <Eng_Name>.....</Eng_Name>
        <Discr>.....</Discr>
        <Type>.....</Type>
        </Parameter>

        <Parameter>
        <Eng_Name>......</Eng_Name>
        <Discr>.........</Discr>
        <Type>.................</Type>
        </Parameter>
</Object>

        <Object name="Car">
        <Struct_Name>tb_Car</Struct_Name>
        <Owner> ..... </Owner>
           <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
        <Eng_Name>.....</Eng_Name>
        <Discr>.....</Discr>
        <Type>.....</Type>
        </Parameter>

        <Parameter>
        <Eng_Name>......</Eng_Name>
        <Discr>.........</Discr>
        <Type>.................</Type>
        </Parameter>
   </Object>
</Dictionary>
```

i try to read this xml like this:

```
foreach(var Object in Objects)
print the whole elements values
   foreach(var Parameter in Parameters Of Current Object)
      print the whole elements of current parameter
```

i try with 2 foreach and its not working always get exception the object is not set to instance of object something like this.
there is a way to read this xml like I want?

Comment: Why don't you use existing XML solution, like LINQ to XML?

Comment: Try using linq its very good for exactly this type of thing.

Comment: i serach about linq but i dont get the answer that i want =

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) to get what you want, for example, you want to get all parameters:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");
XmlNodeList parameters = doc.SelectNodes("Dictionary/Object/Parameters/Parameter"); 
// or doc.SelectNodes("//Parameter"); 
foreach(XmlNode parameter in parameters)
{
    // print the whole element
}
```

Hopeful it's helpful.
By the way, in you xml, the "Parameters" tag is not closed.